# Select Multiple emails and save specific attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code that I found on the Internet, which saves attachments from selected emails to specific folder. All emails that I receive to that specific mailbox are in PDF.

Problem: Whenever there is a logo in a signature of an email or any kind of image on the body of the email, it also saves all those images as separate files.
Is there a way actually to change this code so it saves only PDF files from selected emails?

```
Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim olSelection As Selection
Dim olMail As Object
Dim olAttachments As Attachments
Dim FileCount As Long, i As Long
Dim SaveFolderPath As String

On Error GoTo errHandle
SaveFolderPath = "path"
Set olSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each olMail In olSelection
    If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then
        Set olAttachments = olMail.Attachments
        FileCount = olAttachments.Count

        If FileCount > 0 Then
            For i = FileCount To 1 Step -1
                olAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile SaveFolderPath & olAttachments.item(i).FileName
            Next i
        End If

        Set olAttachments = Nothing
    End If
Next olMail

Exit Sub
   errHandle:
   MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know how it works

Comment: it worked just the way I wanted it to work. thanks

Comment: Just done it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Simply look at the last 4 characters in a filename*

*Example*

```
        If LCase$(Right$(olAttachments.Item(i).FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
            olAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile SaveFolderPath & olAttachments.Item(i).FileName
        End If
```